# Typo3 LTS9 Routing: ReUse config.YAML

Tags: yaml, typo3

What's the right way to reuse config.yaml for routing?

Situation:
I have a typo3 installation with different websites. The routing-config with more than 200 lines is saved in:
\typo3conf\sites\website**1**\config.yaml

**What the right way to use this config.yaml with all other websites** and only reconfig the differences in:
\typo3conf\sites\website**2-100**\config.yaml

With typoscript this where easy. Is there a way to use this:

```
1. <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:\typo3conf\sites\website1\config.yaml">
2. Overide differences like "rootPageID: 2" or delete configs with ">"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use TYPO3v9, you can use `imports:`.

### Documentation:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Yaml/Index.html

From TYPOv10 on they can be relative, too:

### Changelog:

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.1/Feature-88742-ImportYamlFilesRelativeToTheCurrentYamlFile.html

Comment: Then maybe the "include relative" feature came later. I didn't find an earlier ChangeLog.

Comment: @NextThu.: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. Yes, it works with LTS 9 too (9.5.14).

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate Jonas' hint, here a more concrete example:

Site configuration for the single site which is similar to all other and thus should be as short as possible, stored in `sites/mysite/config.yaml`

```
rootPageId: 14523 
base: 'https://www.mysite.mytld' 

imports:
  - { resource: "EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/defaultSiteConf.yaml" }
```

Content of `EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/defaultSiteConf.yaml`, the default config shared for basically all sites (although exceptions are possible).

```
 imports:
  - { resource: "EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/errorHandling.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/language.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/route.pages.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/route.tt_news.yaml" }
```

Content of `EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/language.yaml`, as an example that the default config can be split into multiple files to track changes more easily

```
languages:
  - title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
    languageId: '0'
  - title: English
    enabled: true
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_GB.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-GB
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: gb
    languageId: '1'
```

Comment: Any idea how to disable e.g. a single language in a specific site configuration by setting it's enable property to false?

Comment: Or adding a limitToPages for specific route enhancer over a default definition?

Comment: just make a second language config. think inclusive like adding stuff, not like "everything, except..."

Comment: @NextThu.: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. It works perfectly with LTS 9 (9.5.14).