# Typo3 yaml - How to remove a array?

Tags: yaml, typo3

I use "imports" to load different files in one **config.yaml** file (for many websites - with typo3 LTS-9).

```
 imports:
  - { resource: "EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/errorHandling.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/language.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/route.pages.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:mysitepackage/Configuration/Sites/route.tt_news.yaml" }
```

Example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020624/12840570

**How to remove a full array with many sub-arrays in the config.yaml**? (I tested to set `arrayKey: [null]`. Didn't work.)

With typoscript this where easy. For Example: `routeEnhancers.subarray1.subarray2 >`
**Documentation**: [Typoscript - Object-Unsetting](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax.html#object-unsetting-the-sign)

Comment: Have you tried `arrayKey: ~` (so YAML NULL)?

Comment: Thank you Mathias, but it's not working, the subarrays of arrayKey still exist. 
@All: **I'm still looking for a solution. Please help me!** :-)